# Scan a SQL Server for Stored Procedures with Dynamic SQL evaluations

Tags: sql

Is there a procedure which I can use to scan a database's stored procedures for dynamic query evaluation?  This is in the interest in providing some assurance against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have just generated SQL scripts for the database, and analyzed those for uses of EXEC/EXECUTE as a quick check.